# Connect to Apache drill from Python

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, apache-drill

Does anyone know how to set up a connection to Apache drill from python?

Normally, the connection via pyodbc library is like:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(connectionString)
```

The connection string generally has the format "DSN = ***; UID = ***; PWD = ***". I am just not sure how to set up the connection string here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Another alternative solution is to use https://github.com/PythonicNinja/pydrill

```
pip install pydrill
```

connection is easy:

```
drill = PyDrill(host='localhost', port=8047)
```

or using env variable:

```
PYDRILL_HOST='127.0.0.1' 
PYDRILL_PORT=8047
```

usage in ipython:

```
ipython
from pydrill.client import PyDrill
drill = PyDrill()
drill.query(sql)
```

You can query and interact with profile/storage options:

```
drill = PyDrill()
drill.storage_enable('mongo')
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `~/.odbc.ini` to configure either a direct mode connection (directly to a Drillbit) or a cluster mode connection with your zookeeper quorum details.

```
[ODBC]
Trace=no

[ODBC Data Sources]
[drill64]
# This key is not necessary and is only to give a description of the data source.
Description=MapR Drill ODBC Driver (64-bit) DSN

# Driver: The location where the ODBC driver is installed to.
Driver=/opt/mapr/drillodbc/lib/64/libmaprdrillodbc64.so

ConnectionType=ZooKeeper
ZKQuorum=maprdemo:5181
ZKClusterID=mapr_demo_com-drillbits
AuthenticationType=No Authentication
Catalog=DRILL
Schema=
```

Example code snippet connects to Drill and runs a query:

```
import pyodbc
from pandas import *

# initialize the connection
conn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=drill64", autocommit=True)
cursor = conn.cursor()

# setup the query and run it
s = <SQL Query HERE>

# fetch and display filtered output
cursor.execute(s)
```

Check [blog](https://www.mapr.com/blog/using-drill-programmatically-python-r-and-perl) for more details.